# Image in Tailwind does not resize based on screen size

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I tried to resize the image based on the screen size but it's not working.

```
<div class="max-w-4xl mx-auto">
    <img class="rounded-full -mt-10 ml-3 h-20 w-20 md:h-30 md:w-30 border-[6px] border-white bg-white"
         src="https://api.lorem.space/image/face?w=150&h=150" alt="profile picture">
</div>
```

What did I do wrong on this code?

Comment: there is no `w-30` class by default

Comment: Yup, just checked it. There's no w-30. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fixed it. Thanks to @doğukan for pointing out.

```
<div class="max-w-4xl mx-auto">
    <img class="rounded-full -mt-10 md:-mt-16 ml-3 md:ml-0 h-20 w-20 md:h-32 md:w-32 border-[6px] border-white bg-white"
         src="https://api.lorem.space/image?w=150&h=150" alt="profile picture">
</div>
```